# MBProgressHUD horizontal progress bar xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, mbprogresshud

I need to show the status of loading in horizontal progress bar.
I am using the package MBProgressHUD in xamarin ios

I have this method,

```
public void ShowProgressBar(string title, string message, int max, int 
progress)
{
UIViewController controller = 
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
hud = new MTMBProgressHUD(controller.View);
controller.View.AddSubview(hud);
hud.Color = UIColor.Clear.FromHex(0x8BC34A);
hud.Mode = MBProgressHUDMode.DeterminateHorizontalBar;
hud.Progress = progress;
}
```

max value is 18, and progress parameter starts from 1 and this method calls 18 times.
when this method first call'd, progress bar fully loads, which is wrong.
How to load this progress based on the progress value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you declared the parameters `progress` as `int` .In fact ,you should declare it as `float` , because the range of progress is from `0` to`1`.
 For example ,you can improve your code as following:

```
public void ShowProgressBar(string title, string message, int max, int time) //time means the number of you call this method .from 1-18
    {
        UIViewController controller =
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        hud = new MTMBProgressHUD(controller.View);
        controller.View.AddSubview(hud);
        hud.Color = UIColor.Clear.FromHex(0x8BC34A);
        hud.Mode = MBProgressHUDMode.DeterminateHorizontalBar;

        float progress = time / 18.0f;

        hud.Progress = progress;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @LucasZ it worked.Also is there any way to show progress in percentage right beside the horizontal bar?